# How to create multiple files?

Tags: command-line, multiple-files

While working on something like laravel, I end up creating the same view files index.blade.php, create.blade.php, show.blade.php within different folders like views/articles, views/comments, etc using the nerdTree mostly.

Is there a way to create the files from the command mode or through any plugin, for which i can create a key mapping to speed up things ?

Comment: How about something like `:!touch views/{articles,comments}/{index,create,show}.blade.php`?

Comment: @Rastapopoulos thats a nice one, thanx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a bunch of filenamed buffers from within vim using `:argadd`:

```
:argadd dir1/index.blade.php dir2/create.blade.php foo/show.blade.php
```

You can also use the syntax

```
:argadd dir/{foo,bar}.php
```

From there, you can switch between buffers using `:next`/`:Next`, `:buffer` or any other way.

**Note**: vim does not default write the empty buffers to disk unless you explicitly `:w` them.  You can easily create them all on disk using:

```
:argdo w
```

The plugin `vim-projectionist` is designed for this use case:

https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist

and the `vim-laravel` plugin already has support for `vim-projectionist`

https://github.com/noahfrederick/vim-laravel

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
command! -nargs=* MakeLaravelFiles call MakeLaravelFiles()
function! MakeLaravelFiles()
  !touch /path/to/first/file /path/to/second/file /path/to/third/file
endfunction
```

And then setup a keymapping to that function, aka

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>ml :MakeLaravelFiles<CR>
```

(Note: this snippet creates blank files, but you can use any CLI command you prefer instead of `touch`)